# How do I allow the user to select an existing IIS website to install to using WiX?

Tags: iis, wix, windows-installer

Does anyone know of a **complete**, downloadable/copyable example of a WiX installer that allows the user to select an existing website when installing a web application?

I'm trying to get this working and, after seeing that it seems to be a significant piece of work, I'd like to get an example running first so that I have a working project to base my own work on.

I found [this](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/cm-basics/12907-installing-a-web-application-to-an-existing-iis-website-using-wix3) (code is pasted as images) and [this](http://www.weask.us/entry/wix-select-iis-website) (can't get it running).

Just to confirm... Is it **really** as much work as the sites above suggest to allow a user to select the site to install to? Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [blog post](http://blog.torresdal.net/CommentView,guid,FE27427F-FF4F-4056-BC50-C98E23227C6D.aspx) that does the custom action in C# and has a complete downloadable sample. Pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be quite a bit of work to do it in WiX.   I don't typically give a user this much choice.  You might just want to do it as an after install configuration step if it's important to you.